# How to make a loading graphic in WPF XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

So I have a little WPF XAML that gets the titles of my RSS feed and puts them in a ListBox.

However, it takes about 2 seconds to load.

How can I have put some kind of AJAXy spinning graphic in the ListBox until the data is there?

Here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="ExternalColors" Source="http://www.tanguay.info/web/rss" XPath="/"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBlock Text="RSS Feeds:"/>
        <ListBox Name="lbColor" Height="200" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ExternalColors}, XPath=//item/title}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="You selected this feed:"/>
        <TextBox
            Text="{Binding ElementName=lbColor, Path=SelectedValue}"
            Background="{Binding ElementName=lbColor, Path=SelectedValue}">
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution for this is to implement a asynchronous layer between my data and WPF. This totally decouples WPF from any delays on the data side and gives me nice events and properties to trigger and bind against.

I built this on top of the [View Model or Presenter Model architecture](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/10/11/datamodel-view-viewmodel-pattern-series.aspx). I've written [a blog post about the basics](http://dasz.at/index.php/2008/11/doing-gui-architecture-the-right-way/) and a longer piece about [my approach to asynchronous View Models](http://dasz.at/index.php/2009/02/a-quick-sketch-of-asynchronous-view-models/).

Here is the XAML of the spinner. In the `DataContext` it needs the View Model that does the loading. Depending on its `State`, the `LoadingIndicator` will make itself visible and collapse again.

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.WPF.CustomControls.LoadingIndicator"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Height="20"
             Width="20">
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}"
                             Value="Active">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}"
                             Value="Loading">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}"
                             Value="Invalid">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard TargetName="Rotator"
                            TargetProperty="Angle">
                    <DoubleAnimation By="360"
                                     Duration="0:0:2"
                                     RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Aqua"
               StrokeThickness="2"
               Width="10"
               Height="10">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="Rotator"
                             Angle="0"
                             CenterX="5"
                             CenterY="5" />
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</UserControl>
```

[Source Copyright © 2009 [dasz.at OG](http://dasz.at/); This work is licensed under a [MIT License](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).]

Answer (score 1):

You could could create the spinny-loady-thingy and add it to the AdornerLayer of the ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

The following videos are from mix08 and walk you through doing exactly what you want.

[Part 1](http://sessions.visitmix.com/?selectedSearch=CT01)

[Part 2](http://sessions.visitmix.com/?selectedSearch=CT02)

(watch in succession if possible. it is in silverlight but will point you in the right direction.)

Have Fun.

Answer (score 0):

You could exploit the `IsAsynchronous` property of the `XmlDataProvider` together with the `DataChanged` event (I didn't try): have a look at the documentation. ;-)